# Horizontal bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with bootstrap for the first time. Right now I'm trying to make a simple navigation bar.

I've got this code, which I would hope would make a horizontal navigation bar accross the top of the page (not unlike what you see on stackoverflow.com), but instead I get this:[image]

The code I have looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="/ph.png" height="30" alt="">
            </a>
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">LATEST</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">REVIEWERS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @CommercialSuicide That doesn't seem to have any affect.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the Bootstrap CSS this way...

```css
/* make sidebar nav vertical */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar-nav .navbar .navbar-collapse {
    padding: 0;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .sidebar-nav .navbar ul {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  .sidebar-nav .navbar li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  .sidebar-nav .navbar li a {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="sidebar-nav">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="/ph.png" height="30" alt="">
    </a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">LATEST</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">REVIEWERS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Bootstrap 4 And the solution was to add navbar-toggleable-sm on class of nav.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-light">
```